# SDL_ConvertSurface() causes break

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sdl, sdl-2

> I have the following piece of code where among with lot of other stuff (which i didn't include in this topic), i'm trying to start up sdl, create a render and load some sprites.
>
> Everything compiles just fine but when i run my application a break is caused saying: **Unhandled exception at 0x681252D5 (SDL.dll) in Carribean World SDL.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x16161804**
>
> The break occurs and the point where i use the **SDL_ConvertSurface()** function
>
> Can anyone help me out, i can't see what's wrong

Declerations:

```
SDL_Texture* background = NULL;
SDL_Surface* tmp = NULL;
SDL_Surface* surface = NULL;

SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Carribean World",
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
    1360, 768,
    SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);

SDL_Surface* screen = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);

SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);

SDL_PixelFormat* fmt = screen->format;
```

IN MAIN:
Initialize all SDL subsystems

```
if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == -1)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Load images to surfaces

```
if ((tmp = IMG_Load("images/water.jpg")) == NULL)
{
    cout << "SDL_SetVideoMode() Failed: " << SDL_GetError() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Right here a break is caused

```
if ((surface = SDL_ConvertSurface(tmp, fmt, 0)) == NULL)
{
    cout << "SDL_ConvertSurface() Failed: " << SDL_GetError() << endl;
}
background = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, tmp);
```

Comment: You shouldn't compare the return value of `SDL_Init` to `-1` as it is only guaranteed to be negative, not necessarily `-1`.

Comment: i changed it to < 0, returning a message but the problem is not there, it still breaks at **SDL_ConvertSurface**

Comment: What does "returning a message" mean?

Comment: **cout<<SDL_GetError();**

Comment: I believe the problem is not with sdl_int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't checked return value of `SDL_GetWindowSurface`. But anyway, SDL documentation for this [function](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowSurface) says 'You may not combine this with 3D or the rendering API on this window.'. So either you exclusively use SDL_Renderer API, **or** using `SDL_BlitSurface` and alike and after that calling `SDL_UpdateWindowSurface`, but you can't use both.

Comment: I'm not sure if i undrestand what is causing the break. How should it be instead? Forgive my ignorance but i have just two days exp with sdl

Comment: Don't create renderer, I suppose. And don't use textures. *OR* use textures but don't use screen surface - there is no need to convert to display format in that case, textures creation chooses best format itself.